# twilio sms with python

Tags: sms, twilio

i want this to be converted into php, anyone please. i am doing marketing application coding to send bulk sms

```
from flask import Flask, request

from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient

app = Flask(__name__)

# put your own credentials here 
ACCOUNT_SID = 'YOUR_ACCOUNT_SID' 
AUTH_TOKEN = 'YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN' 

client = TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN)

@app.route('/sms', methods=['POST'])
def send_sms():
    message = client.messages.create(
        to=request.form['To'], 
        from_='YOUR_TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER', 
        body=request.form['Body'],
    )

    return message.sid

if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run()
```

Comment: application is in swift3,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There is a whole page of documentation on [how to send an SMS using Twilio and PHP right here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/sms/sending-via-rest).

In short though, to replicate the Python, you should [download or install the PHP helper library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/php) to your project. Then this code should work:

```
<?php
    require_once "vendor/autoload.php";
    use Twilio\Rest\Client;

    $AccountSid = "YOUR_ACCOUNTS_SID";
    $AuthToken = "YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN";

    $client = new Client($AccountSid, $AuthToken);

    $sms = $client->messages->create(
        $_REQUEST['To'],
        array(
            'from' => "YOUR_TWILIO_NUMBER", 
            'body' => $_REQUEST['Body']
        )
    );
    echo "Sent message";
```

I recommend for the full instructions to [follow the documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/sms/sending-via-rest).